# pythonでバイナリデータの読みこみ時に値が変わっているのはなぜ？

Tags: python

バイナリエディタで開くと次のようなデータがあります。

> 00 00 0B D7 15 04 04 04 38 00 00 00 13 E8 00 00
>   ～以下略

次のようなコードでファイルを読み込み、データを取り出そうとすると、
値が若干変わっており、上の38の部分が8になってしまっていました。

```
f = open(inputfiles,"rb")
f.read(40)
```

> 00 00 0B D7 15 04 04 04 8 00 00 00 13 E8 00 00

他にもいくつかの箇所で読み込むと値が変わっているようです。

可変長の地震関係で使われるwinフォーマットというやつなのですが、
読みこみ途中で値が変わってしまっていて困っています。
どうやったら元のままの値で読み込めますか？

Comment: みなさんご回答ありがとうございます。
こんなに早くアドバイス頂けると思っていませんでした。
結局勘違いしていたのはその通りでした。
この質問欄にはopenの"rb"をちゃんと記載していたのですが、
私のプログラム上で色々試していたら、いつの間にか"b"を消してしまっていたのに気づかなかったようです。
お騒がせしました。コメントくださった皆さんありがとうございます。

Answer (score 3):

読み込んだデータの先頭から9byte目ですね。

```
>>> f = open(inputfiles,"rb")
>>> data = f.read(40)
>>> data[8]
'8'
```

データとしてはちゃんと '0x38' のままです。

```
>>> hex(ord(data[8]))
'0x38'
```

16進数の38がASCII文字の'8'だったので、Pythonがインタラクティブシェルでそのように表示したのを勘違いした、ということでしょう（他の方の回答通りです）

```
>>> hex(ord('\x38'))
'0x38'
>>> hex(ord('8'))
'0x38'
```

これは、Python2でbyte列を扱うのも、文字列(非Unicode文字)を扱うのも、str型で行っているためで、str型を画面に表示するときにデータを文字として解釈しているためです。メモリ上の値はちゃんと0x38なので、画面にprintするときだけ別の方法(他の方の回答にあるような)を使えば良いでしょう。

Answer (score 1):

どのように値を確認したのかよくわからないのですが、0x38はASCIIで"8"になります。データとしては0x38と読んでいるが、その中身を確認する過程で文字として表示なり解釈してしまっているため"8"になっているだけではありませんか。

Answer (score 1):

read() した結果をどう処理、確認してますか？

```
    data = f.read(40)
    print ['0x%x' % ord(x) for x in data]
```

として本当に 38 が 8 になってますか？ 0x38 は "8" の ascii コードなので、単に勘違いしているように見えます。

```
    data = bytearray(f.read(40))
```

とbytearrayに入れれば、入力をバイト列として処理できます。open() の "b" に、「read() の結果をバイト列として扱う」という意味は残念ながらありません。

Comment: open()に'b'指定で、read()の結果をバイト列として扱いますよ。
インタラクティブシェルやprintなどでの出力を見て勘違いしている、というのはその通りでしょう。

Comment: 普段 2.x しか使ってないので気づきませんでしたが、3.x だとちゃんと bytes 返しますね。勉強になりました。